# NestedScrollView not scrolling my main recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So' I have a recyclerview and inside this recyclerview another one, I want to scroll the innter recyclerview, I have made it work with the followin

This is the layout inside the main recyclerview

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Now, if I dont have enought items in my inner recyclerview , the scrolling of the main recyclerview will not work, instead if I place

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`  will make my main recyclerview scroll when no enought elemetns are inside the inner recyclerview, but I want to make the innter recyclerview scroll the main one even when there is no enought elements inside of it, instead the scrolling should be doing from the main recyclerview view

Answer (score 0):

change match_parent to wrap_content, thus it is always expanded and non-scrollable. Now only NestedScrollView should handle all scroll by itself, but if its not - try to change ExpandableListView to smth newer like RecyclerView from Android Support Library 23.2.1 update, where tag wrap_content works like a charm.

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```